# Reading csv file gives runtime error?

Tags: python, csv, runtimeerror

I copied a python script from another answered question on this site.  I am using arcgis 10.2.2.  It returns an error and produces an empty shapefile; it has headers but no data.  Can someone look at the script below and identify the problem?

---

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readLine'
```

---

```
import arcpy

outPath = r"S:\GIS data\Matthew Damage areas" #output path for the feature class
featureClass = "roadSegments.shp" #the name of your shapefile
spatialRef = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984") #the spatial reference you want; set it to whatever you want

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outPath, featureClass, "POLYLINE", " ", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", spatialRef) #sets up the shapefile we're using

arcpy.AddField_management(outPath + "\\" + featureClass, "segmentID", "SHORT", 15) #I assume that each segment has some sort of ID number that you might want to import into

roadArray = arcpy.Array() #this will hold the coordinates for each line segment until we write it to the shapefile.

roadFile = open(r"S:\GIS data\Matthew Damage areas\roadlines.csv") #the path to your road lines file
headerLine = roadFile.readLine()
indexList = headerLine.split(",")

#now we need the index locations for the columns that contain the latitude and longitude points for the starting and ending points for each line segment.  I'm also assuming that each segment has some sort of ID value in your segment.  Change the value inside the parenthesis to reflect whatever you named your column for those values.

idValueIndex = indexList.index('segmentID')
fromLatValueIndex = indexList.index('fromLatitude')
fromLongValueIndex = indexList.index('fromLongitude')
toLatValueIndex = indexList.index('toLatitude')
toLongValueIndex = indexList.index('toLongitude')

roadCursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(outPath + "\\" + featureClass)

for fileLine in roadFile.readlines():
    readLine = fileLine.split(",")
    idNumber = int(readLine[idValueIndex])
    fromLat = float(readLine[fromLatValueIndex])
    fromLong = float(readLine[fromLongValueIndex])
    toLat = float(readLine[toLatValueIndex])
    toLong = float(readLine[toLongValueIndex])

    #now let's add the points and draw the lines
    fromVertex = arcpy.Point(fromLong, fromLat)
    roadArray.add(fromVertex)
    toVertex = arcpy.Point(toLong, toLat)
    roadArray.add(toVertex)

    roadCursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(outPath + "\\" + featureClass)
    feature = roadCursor.newRow()
    polyline = arcpy.Polyline(roadArray, spatialRef)
    feature.shape = polyline
    feature.setValue("segmentID", idNumber) #adds the segmentID in the attribute table

    roadCursor.insertRow(feature)
    roadArray.removeAll()

del roadCursor

print "Finished!"
print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Comment: it's **readline** not **readLine**, python is **case sensitive**. Have a read of file objects https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects . BTW it's not Excel, it's CSV which is a text format.. the use of Excel in the title is a bit of a misnomer which could cause potential readers to ignore this post as CSV is *much* easier to deal with than Excel (.xls). I'll add that tag for you.

Comment: The error is coming from a pure Python part of your code and that part would be better researched/asked at [so].  Once you get that bit working, if you are stuck further along, then revise your question, or ask a new question, to present a code snippet that illustrates what you tried and where you got stuck then.

Comment: Thank you.  That got me to the next error. I will post to stack overflow.  I am new to python.